# How do I get the id of new objects in Hibernate 6.1

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a class marked @Entity

Which have the field:

@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY) public int id;

With hibernate 5.x I could call save on new instance of this object, and then the primary key would be written to the id field.

But this does not work with hibernate 6.1, where the save method is Deprecreated.

The obvious solution would be to use persist instead of save, but that does not generate an id I can get. So how do I generate a now Object with Hibernate 6.1 and get the primary key?

Answer (score 0):

Just `flush()` the session before reading the id from the entity.

Comment: Are you sure that will always work? The documentation for persist in session says that ..." results in generation of an identifier for the given instance. But this may happen asynchronously"

Comment: Yes of course I'm sure. Why don't you just try it?